# Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver on JBoss using HIbernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I've been trying to set up an EJB project at work to learn Hibernate and so far I've been stuck with this error. I've tried almost all soltions I found on SO or elsewhere to no avail. The project has a TimerBean that invokes a methos from another Bean that accesses the database using Hibernate and prints out a stored value. I generated the entity classes from the tables using JPA and manually wrote a mapping file for the generated entity class. Here are the relevant files in my project:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>       
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/accountdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>

    <!-- Hibernate properties -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <!-- Mapping Files -->
    <mapping resource="com/gto/test/Account.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="TestEJB3Project">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <class>com.gto.test.Account</class>
  <class>com.gto.test.Accountaccesslog</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

**AccountAccessBean.java**

```
package com.gto.test;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

@Stateless(mappedName = "AccountAccessBean")
@LocalBean
public class AccountAccessBean {
    public void resigterAccountEvent() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        Account accountEntity = (Account) session.get(Account.class, new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(accountEntity.getId());
    }
}
```

**Account.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.gto.test">
    <class name="Account" table="account">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="accessCount" column="accessCount"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Server Log**

```
15:18:00,184 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections] (EJB default - 1)       HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
15:18:00,184 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 1) WFLYEJB0020: Error invoking timeout for timer: [id=e4f1edcd-d8cb-4f38-9a17-78df26ccc2ea timedObjectId=TestEJB3Project.TestEJB3Project.TimerBean auto-timer?:true persistent?:true   timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@15178ba initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed Jul 27 15:18:30 IST 2016 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT info=Calls AccountAccessBean every 30 seconds]: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.CalendarTimerTask.invokeBeanMethod(CalendarTimerTask.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:155)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl$Task$1.run(TimerServiceImpl.java:1214)
at org.wildfly.extension.requestcontroller.RequestController$QueuedTask$1.run(RequestController.java:497)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
at com.gto.test.AccountAccessBean.resigterAccountEvent(AccountAccessBean.java:44)
at com.gto.test.TimerBean.scheduledTimeout(TimerBean.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:57)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:57)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
... 33 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
... 80 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
... 91 more
```

[Here's a snip of my project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peTKl.png)

Any help is appreciated. I've tried almost all solutions I could find online, but I noticed they were mostly for simple java projects and not for an enterprise one. I also tried creating a simple connection using the JDBC driver to access the DB but that didn't work either. Connections in a simple Java project are working just fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the MySQL JDBC driver isn't (or not correctly) deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did fix the issue but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it or the issue has been actually fixed. I added a **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file to my project in the META-INF directory:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>          
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
        <module name="javax.xml.rpc.api" />
        <module name="javax.rmi.api" />
        <module name="org.omg.api" />
        <module name="configext" />
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

Then, in the server installation root, under modules/ I added a configext/ module/folder and copied all my JAR files into it and added a **module.xml** file to the directory:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="configext">
<dependencies>          
    <module name="javax.api" />
</dependencies>
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="cdi-api-1.1-PFD.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="classmate-1.3.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="el-api-2.2.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="javax.inject-1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="jsr250-api-1.0.jar"/>
</resources>
```

I read somewhere that this adds these packages onto the server's global classpath. I might be entirely wrong but this seems to work. If this is not a permanent fix or the incorrect way to do things, I'm still open to suggestions. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your server to use Mysql? Since you have mentioned JBoss by default both wildfly and EAP use H2 and not Mysql.

Comment: Yes, Data Source is MySQL and is connected.